# R Dummy-variable to be populated from multiple columns

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am a beginner in R and looking to implement dummy variables on a dataset.

I am having a data set with few columns like below -

```
Dataset1
T1  T2  T3
A   C   B
A   C   B
A   C   B
A   D   C
B   D   C
B   E   F
```

I want to add dummy variables to this like dummy,A; dummy,B; dummy,C and so on.. And assign them values as 1 if it is present in either T1, T2 or T3, else 0.

So the final data set should look like -

```
T1  T2  T3  dummy,A dummy,B dummy,C dummy,D dummy,E dummy,F
A   C   B   1   1   1   0   0   0
A   C   B   1   1   1   0   0   0
A   C   B   1   1   1   0   0   0
A   D   C   1   0   1   1   0   0
B   D   C   0   1   1   1   0   0
B   E   F   0   1   0   0   1   1
```

So can anyone please suggest how I can achieve this?

Any help in this regard is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`.  Transpose the 'Dataset1', convert it to `data.frame`, apply the `mtabulate`, change its column names (if needed) and `cbind` with the original 'Dataset1'

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(Dataset1)))
row.names(d1) <- NULL
names(d1) <- paste0("dummy.", names(d1))
cbind(Dataset1, d1)
#   T1 T2 T3 dummy.A dummy.B dummy.C dummy.D dummy.E dummy.F
#1  A  C  B       1       1       1       0       0       0
#2  A  C  B       1       1       1       0       0       0
#3  A  C  B       1       1       1       0       0       0
#4  A  D  C       1       0       1       1       0       0
#5  B  D  C       0       1       1       1       0       0
#6  B  E  F       0       1       0       0       1       1
```

Comment: No idea how you worked that one out based on such a poorly formatted question. I tip my hat to you @akrun.

Comment: @MauritsEvers  I clicked on the edit button where the format is correct.  But, didn't change it as I got busy :=)

Comment: Ah clever. Didn't realise that would make a difference. Thanks for the tip:-)